# Grails renders JSP as blank page

Tags: jsp, grails

I have a Grails application with a JSP page (I'm porting a legacy JSP application). For some reason, the page renders completely blank. Looking at the HTTP headers I see it's 200 with a content length of 0.

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Content-Language: en-US
Content-Type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1
Expires: Thu, 01 Jan 1970 00:00:00 GMT
Set-Cookie: JSESSIONID=1sh9r73vqvukj;Path=/myGrailsApp
Content-Length: 0
Server: Jetty(6.1.12)
```

The page is a combination of HTML, tags (`${property}`), JSP includes (`<jsp:include>`), and short code snippets (`<% code %>`, yes I know this is a bad idea). There is nothing in the log file or console that indicates an error. Is Grails somehow silently hiding an exception or error?

Edit: The problem is related to the JSP `<jsp:include/>` include tag. If I remove all JSP includes then Grails will render. Is Grails compatible with JSP? Since JSP functionality is provided by the web application (Jetty, Tomcat) I would think yes.

Edit: This occurs with Grails 1.0.4 and 1.1 beta 2 (1.1 claims to have added JSP support)

Comment: Oops, now you mention 1.1 beta and JSP support (or not) I guess I need to edit my answer to your rant question.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, Grails is compatible with JSP.

Completely blank?  So if you "show source" you get nothing?

If you're an IntelliJ user you can install the Grails plug-in, set a breakpoint and step through the code to see what's happening.

The other things I'd check are version and JSTL standards.  Those change depending on the version of servlet/JSP engine you're using.

Comment: Yup, it's completely blank. Show source is blank (as the Content-Length is 0).

Comment: Oh, my.  I've got nothing then.  Which servlet/JSP engine are you using, Jetty or Tomcat?  Which version?

Comment: Jetty, whichever version is included in Grails

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you're not deploying your tag libraries properly.  We need to know the app server you are using to be able to help you further.

Edit: Another thought - perhaps the include tag is working, but there is a compile error in the content being included.  Have you tried just returning the included content?

Answer (score 0):

Obviously, you would have solved your problem by this time but this solution is for others.

Today I encountered same problem:

This is code section from `main.gsp` (LAYOUT)

```
<head>
    <g:layoutTitle default="Grails" />
    <g:layoutHead />
    <g:javascript src="jquery-1.6.1.min.js" />
</head>
```

And this is my `index.gsp`

```
<head>
    <title>${title}</title>
    <meta name="layout" content="main" />
</head>
```

What I was doing is passing dynamically constructed `title` from `index.gsp` and using layout `main`. `title` is a required attribute of html `head` tag. So by mistake, I was passing title as `null` value. and it was not showing expected page.

So the solution is:

- if you need static title, don't use `title` tag in you gsp file. In the above case it will use `Grails` as title by default.
- If you need dynamic title then make sure It is not `null` value.

You may have different problem but this may also cause blank page.